# Working as contractor in Australia as foreign citizen (EU)

Tags: working-visas, australia, freelance

I'm an EU-Citizen and I'd like to consider opportunity of working in Australia as IT-specialist (developer).

If I find an opportunity to work there as contractor/freelancer, can I simply register my company there? Or there are special requirements to be met? How do I apply for visa in that case?

As far as I know, Australia grants visa to computer specialists without any problem, because they are needed there, if they want to be employed there. Do the same applies to contractors?

Answer (score 7):

**It's not that simple**.  To legally work in Australia, you must have a work visa, and the most common work visa ([457](http://www.immi.gov.au/visas/pages/457.aspx)) requires a qualified Australian company to sponsor you.  It's possible to [self-sponsor a 457](http://blog.truebluemigration.com/457-visa-self-sponsorship/), meaning you create an Australian company for the primary purpose of hiring yourself, but this is expensive and not risk-free.

Comment: You can also go down the route of applying for a [Skilled Independent visa (subclass 189)](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/189-). Note that the application process is nontrivial: expect it to take 6-9 months and cost a few thousand €€€s